# RecyclerView item click checked state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView`, in which I have a circular `ImageView`, on item click, I want the selected circle image to get highlighted.

I use https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView for circular `ImageView`

I tried but am not getting how to disable the highlighted item of another position other than the current position.

my Adapter code is given below

```
public class AddEventIconsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddEventIconsAdapter.NavigationViewHolder> {

private Context context;
public int mSelectedItem = -1;
List<ChildSpouseCustomModel> listIcons;


public AddEventIconsAdapter(Context context, List<ChildSpouseCustomModel> 
 listIcons) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listIcons = listIcons;


}

@Override
public AddEventIconsAdapter.NavigationViewHolder 
onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_add_icons, parent, false);
    return new AddEventIconsAdapter.NavigationViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AddEventIconsAdapter.NavigationViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Glide.with(context).load(listIcons.get(position).getImgUrl())
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .error(R.drawable.ic_user_placeholder)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.img_EventIcon);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mSelectedItem == position) {
                mSelectedItem=-1;

                holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderWidth(0);
                holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            } else {
                mSelectedItem = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderWidth(5);
                holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listIcons.size();
}


class NavigationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


    private CircleImageView img_EventIcon;


    public NavigationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img_EventIcon = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_parent);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
}
```

my list item xml is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image_parent"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_placeholder" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My expected output: one clicked image highlighted at a time

[image]

My present Output when I run the above code  :

[image]

How can I highlight only the clicked item circle image? is there anyway, can anyone help me to sort it out.

Comment: you have to check mSelectedItem!=-1 if that the case then you have previous value selected then just find view using mSelectedItem and set the border to 0 then continue with your code for selection, second option is just use mSelectedItem condition in  onBindViewHolder method to detect selection as @J Ramesh suggested, its better you go with onBindViewHolder else your state will not be maintained when you scroll your recyclerview.

Comment: add this code in onBindViewHolder       if (mSelectedItem != -1 && mSelectedItem != position) {
                            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderWidth(0);
                            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                        } else {
                            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderWidth(5);
                            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                        }

Comment: @JRamesh it is not working, the highlighted states of other items other than the current item is not cleared

Comment: @Pavan how can I change the view of items at position "x" other than the current position. is there any way

Comment: @AmruthaSaj  you are not notifyDataSetChanged(); in if statement of click listener

Comment: @AmruthaSaj change condition that i was commented like this if (mSelectedItem == -1 || mSelectedItem != position) {

Comment: @AmruthaSaj your clicklisteners code is correct only change condition onBindView method

Comment: @JRamesh now its working fine, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check with this answer this will manage selection and removal

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final AddEventIconsAdapter.NavigationViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Glide.with(context).load(listIcons.get(position).getImgUrl())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .error(R.drawable.ic_user_placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.img_EventIcon);

        if(mSelectedItem == position)
        {
            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderWidth(5);
            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        }
        else
        {
            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderWidth(0);
            holder.img_EventIcon.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mSelectedItem == position) {
                    mSelectedItem=-1;



                } else {
                    mSelectedItem = position;

                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: glad it helped and hope you get to know recyclerview behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class NavigationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

-->>in

public NavigationViewHolder(View itemView) {

-->> in 

 imageview initiation..

 -->> below

 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  Toast.makeText(contact, "Any message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
            }
        });
```

Comment: my item click is working fine. my issue is with highlighting the selected item circle image view